# node.js cassandra-driver gives error: Object has no method 'setMaxListeners'

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

I have jasmine test code, to test if node.js cassandra-driver connects to cassandra appropriately. (yes, i know that database connection is not a subject of unit testing)

```
var config = require('../config.js');
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');

describe('Testing connectivity regarding to config.js', function() {

    it('should connect to cassandra', function() {
        var client = cassandra.Client({
            contactPoints: config.cassandra.hosts,
            keyspace: config.cassandra.keyspace
        });

    });
});
```

This gives me an error as below :

```
Testing connectivity regarding to config.js should connect to cassandra
  TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setMaxListeners'  TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setMaxListeners'
      at Object.Client (/Users/alkimake/Projects/analist/meta-data-cache/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/client.js:51:8)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alkimake/Projects/analist/meta-data-cache/spec/connect-spec.js:12:32)
      at attemptSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1620:12)
      at QueueRunner.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1608:9)
      at QueueRunner.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1595:10)
      at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:508:35)
      at Spec.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:295:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1834:37)
      at attemptAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1644:12)
      at QueueRunner.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1606:16)
```

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using? `setMaxListeners` is a method in Node.js http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n

Comment: I am using version 0.10.33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the "new" keyword to construct a new instance.

```
var client = new cassandra.Client({...});
```